# Error: Cannot destructure property 'params' of 'match' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Hi I am currently trying to create a page that displays information on Album covers.

After clicking on one of the album covers, I want to redirect to another page which provides more information to the user about that specific album (i.e tracklist, etc..) [It looks like this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrayL.png)

Question: Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

Here is the code for the Search page which lists out all the albums.

```
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { getSearch } from '../../services/backendService';
import {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

import '../../styles/Search.css';
import AlbumPage from '../Album';


const ExploreSearch = (props) => {
    
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    useEffect( () =>{
        console.log(text)
    },[text])

    const boxValue = (query) =>{
        setSearchValue(query)
    } 

    const search = (query) => {
        getSearch(query, setText)
        
    }
    
   const getDict = (dict) => {
        const result = [['Key', 'Value']];
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
            result.push([key, value]);
        }
        return result;
      } 

      

    return (
        <div>
            <Container className ="mb-5">
                <Row>
                    <Col md = {3}></Col>
                    <Col>
                        <Form onKeyDown={(e) => {
                                if( e.key === 'Enter') {
                                    e.preventDefault(); 
                                    search(searchValue);}}}>
                                        
                            
                            <Form.Control id = "searchLeft" type='text' placeholder={'Search for an Album'} value={searchValue} onChange={(e) => { boxValue(e.target.value) }} >
                            </Form.Control>

                            <Button id = "searchRight" variant="light" onClick={(_) => search(searchValue)} >
                                Search
                            </Button>
                            
                        </Form>
                        
                    </Col>
                    <Col md = {3}></Col>
                </Row>
                <div className={"search-results"} >
                    {text.results?.slice(0,5).map((items, index) => { return(
                        
                            <div className='album-output' key={index} style={{color: "white", padding: "5px", display: "inline-block"}}>
                               <div style={{fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: "bold"}}> {items.title} </div> <br/> <Link to={`/album/${items.id}`}>
                                <img style={{width:"60%"}} src={items.cover_image} alt="album cover"></img> </Link> <div style={{fontSize: "18px"}}><br/> Released Year {items.year} <br/> Genres: {items.genre} 
                                <br/> Format: {items.format.join(', ')} <br/> </div> <div>
                                <Chart
                                        chartType="Bar"
                                        data={getDict(items.community)}
                                        width="100%"
                                        height="300px"
                                        options = {{
                                            title: "Population of Largest U.S. Cities",
                                            
                                            hAxis: {
                                              title: "Total Population",
                                            },
                                            vAxis: {
                                              title: "City",
                                            },
                                        }}
                                        />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    }

            </div>
            </Container>
        
            

        </div>
    )


}

export default ExploreSearch;
```

And then this is the albums page I have created

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getAlbum } from '../services/backendService';
import Chart from 'react-google-charts';

const Album = ({ match }) => {
  const [album, setAlbum] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { params: { albumId } } = match;
    getAlbum(albumId, setAlbum);
  }, [match]);

  const getDict = (dict) => {
    const result = [['Key', 'Value']];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
        result.push([key, value]);
    }
    return result;
  } 

  if (!album) {
    return <div>No album found.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="albums">
      <h1>{album.title}</h1>
      <img src={album.cover_image} alt="album cover"></img>
      <div>Released Year: {album.year}</div>
      <div>Genres: {album.genre}</div>
      <div>Format: {album.format.join(', ')}</div>
      <Chart
        chartType="Bar"
        data={getDict(album.community)}
        width="100%"
        height="300px"
        options={{
          title: 'Community data',
          chartArea: { width: '50%' },
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Value',
            minValue: 0,
          },
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Key',
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Album;
```

This is the App.js file.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Explore from './components/Explore.js'
import Profile from './components/Profile.js';
import Albums from './components/Album.js';
import Home from './components/Home.js';
import './styles/App.css';
import { BrowserRouter,Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  return (
    <div style={{height: '100%'}} className = "border bg-dark">
      
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path='/explore' element={<Explore/>} />
          <Route path ='/album/:albumId' component={Albums} />
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile msg = ""/>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @DrewReese my page isn't showing up as shown in the last link

Comment: `component={Albums}` should be `element={<Albums />}`.

Comment: In `react-router-dom@6` there are no route props, i.e. no `match` prop. Use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook in `Album`. Also, in the future try not to change the post topic after it's already been answered or marked as a duplicate or closed as doing so may likely invalidate any existing answers or duplication links.